# Unable to read a subpackage when building using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project which i am building using maven. In this project i have "**main**" package named : `pentaho.kettle.step.plugs.spchr` and a sub-package named : `pentaho.kettle.step.plugs.spchr.messages`. Check the image as below:

[image]

But i am building my project using maven, its not able to detect the sub-package content. *Note:* It is not throwing the error; but not showing the expected result.

When i tried to manually **export** the project without building using maven, it worked perfectly.

Am i missing something in here? Please help :)

The **pom.xml** for this project is in [here](https://github.com/rishuatgithub/Pentaho/blob/master/SpecialCharacterRemover/pentaho-kettle-step-spchr/pom.xml).

Screenshot of the pom.xml used in the project:

[image: Screenshot of the pom.xml used in the project]

Comment: When you say "it is not showing the expected result", you should be more specific. What **is** it showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your subpackage contains a properties file and no java file, it should be placed inside `src/main/resources/pentaho/kettle/step/plugs/spchr/messages/`. `src/main/java` is for java files only. Static resources always belong to `src/main/resources/`.

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html for further information

Comment: wow great !! i didnt know this !! Thanks @Alexander .. just tried it and it worked !! :)